# Newline in Dialog using SmartEyeglassControlUtils.showDialogMessage method

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

Is it possible to have newlines in the dialogs?
Using `showDialogMessage` of `SmartEyeglassControlUtils` I tried sending text with both `\n` and `<br/>` in it but both not working. `\n` is not visible though. Assuming that it is a better candidate to be used than `<br/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately newline is not supported in dialogs. Because dialogs are designed to be simple and short.

Although you can use regular Android layouts to display more detailed views on SmartEyeglass.